Django ошибка 404 django
Всем доброго времени суток.
Я новичок в цифровом мире. Учусь на Python по ютубу и книге Мэтиза.
Делаю сайт, но возникла проблема с urls. При попытке открыть страницу topics отображается ошибка 404. Меняла urls, но все тщетно.
Далее код из приложения news, в этой папке у меня находится наполнение страниц информацией.
animals/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_UR, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

news/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news_home, name='news_home'),
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('topics', views.topics, name='topics'),
]

news/vews.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Topic, Articles

def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'news/topics.html', context)

news/topics.html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Topics{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for topic in topics %}
        <li>{{ topic }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>Нет ничего</li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

А так же не понимаю, почему в html не отображается цикл for topic in topics. Так как в оболочке все работает.
>>> from news.models import Topic
>>> Topic.objects.order_by('date')
<QuerySet [<Topic: Кошки>, <Topic: Собаки>]>
>>> topics=Topic.objects.all()
>>> for topic in topics:
...     print(topic)
...
Кошки
Собаки
>>>



пробывал не /news/topics/ , а /news/topics?

Aleksey Kaptur,
Вы имеете ввиду в строке прописать http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/topics? Да, пробовала, все-равно 404. Там все-равно в итоге подставляется /. В коде я уже даже не представляю что можно и где прописать.

обычно слэш сам подставляется в конце строки запроса. Попробуйте видоизменить код в news/urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news_home, name='news_home'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
]

Касательно вашей проблемы с django циклом, проверьте находятся ли создаваемые циклом элементы списка в родительском элементе списка (Упорядоченном или Неупорядоченном). Выглядеть это должно примерно так:
<ul>
  {% for topic in topics %}
  <li>{{ topic }}</li>
  {% empty %}
  <li>Нет ничего</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

Или:
<ol>
  {% for topic in topics %}
  <li>{{ topic }}</li>
  {% empty %}
  <li>Нет ничего</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>


Спасибо большое.

path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics') действительно заработал теперь. Становится все более запутанно, почему 'create' и 'create/' работают одинаково, но с topics такой номер не проходит?
В html я не поставила . Хотя несколько раз сверялась с книгой ...

К сожалению я не видел код представления create, поэтому не могу дать вам точный ответ почему код работает без подстановки слэша (Если судить очень поверхностно, это может быть из за перманетного редиректа). Книгу не читал, поэтому не могу сказать из за чего в ней описан не рабочий вариант кода, но я обычно пишу так как описал в ответе. Если ответ вам был полезен отметьте его пожалуйста как полезный, спасибо
